# Prolog: critical section, backtracking, error handling

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I'm trying to write a critical section guarded by a mutex in SWI-Prolog and have been looking at using `setup_call_cleanup/3` and `setup_call_catcher_cleanup/4`.

The problem I have is that my *Goal* is a sequence of operations of which any may fail and that means the system backtracks to the start of `setup_call_cleanup` and calls *Cleanup*. Unfortunately, with backtracking I'm not able to report the error appropriately. To illustrate my issue let's consider this simple example:

```
setup_call_cleanup(
      mutex_lock(mtx),
      ( Step1 = true, Step2 = true, Step3 = true ),
      ( mutex_unlock(mtx), writeln([Step1, Step2, Step3]) ).
```

and compare it with the following:

```
setup_call_cleanup(
      mutex_lock(mtx),
      ( Step1 = true, Step2 = true, fail, Step3 = true ),
      ( mutex_unlock(mtx), writeln([Step1, Step2, Step3]) ).
```

In the first case all is ok -- I can see all steps done. But in the second case I'm not able to see that `Step1` and `Step2` has been carried out. I'd like to see it because they may have external side effects which backtracking cannot undo. Also, I don't want to include error handling within the *Goal* to make the critical section as lean and fast as possible.

I have two ideas:

1. Decorate each step with `nb_setval` to store a value to indicate the completed steps,
2. Re-code steps, so they throw exceptions that carry details of the problem.

The former will make code rather bloated, whereas the latter seems too heavyweight for my needs. Is there anything like `setup_nb_call_cleanup`?

Comment: The second approach is definitely already *much* better than the first suggestion! When dealing with exceptions, always also think about what happens with *nested* invocations. Impure predicates like global updates make this a nightmare or even impossible to get right.

Comment: @mat: hmm, yes and no. If some steps are as simple as `assert(some_fact)`, wrapping those with the throw clause may make it more complicated than needed, I think. Also, I'm not sure about the cost of `throw` and `catch` when compared to `nb_setval`... I really wanted the critical section to be fast.

Comment: Please use `time/1` or `statistics/2` to test the performance of both approaches. This will make sure that you use the fastest version. Very frequently,  impure solutions are also among the slowest.

Comment: The other issue with approach (2) is that sometimes it's hard to think about a situation as an exception when it's just a fail. For example, `some_fact` does not hold in which case it is not an exception. I really would like to see something like `nb_catch` or `nb_setup_call_cleanup`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Jan for the inspiration; very useful. I ended up coding a similar `step_by_step` rule:

```
step_by_step(Goal, Steps, Error) :-
    step_by_step_(Goal, 0, Steps, Error).

step_by_step_((A, B), InStep, OutStep, Error) :-
    !,
    step_by_step_(A, InStep, OutStep1, Error),
    ( var(Error) ->
        step_by_step_(B, OutStep1, OutStep, Error)
    ;
        OutStep = InStep
    ).

step_by_step_(Goal, InStep, OutStep, Error) :-
    ( catch(Goal, Ex, (Error = exception(Ex), OutStep = InStep)) *->
        (OutStep is InStep + 1 ; true), !
    ;
        Error = false(Goal),
        OutStep = InStep
    ).
```

I'm not happy with `(OutStep is InStep + 1 ; true), !` but wasn't able to find a better way.

Anyway, the rule gives me what I want:

-- if all goes ok, it just runs all steps in sequence:

```
?- step_by_step((Step1 = true, Step2 = true, Step3 = true), Steps, Error).
Step1 = Step2, Step2 = Step3, Step3 = true,
Steps = 3.
```

-- if one of the step fails or throws an exception, it returns the number of steps completed successfully and the failed goal:

```
?- step_by_step((Step1 = true, Step2 = true, fail, Step3 = true), Steps, Error).
Step1 = Step2, Step2 = true,
Steps = 2,
Error = false(fail).
```

or the exception:

```
?- step_by_step((Step1 = true, Step2 = true, throw(bomb), Step3 = true), Steps, Error).
Step1 = Step2, Step2 = true,
Steps = 2,
Error = exception(bomb).
```

Answer (score 2):

The trick, I think, is to run the goals one by one, guarded for errors and failure and return step that failed.  A good start is

```
until_failure((A,B), Result) :-
    !,
    until_failure(A, Result),
    (   var(Result)
    ->  until_failure(B, Result)
    ;   true
    ).
until_failure(G, Result) :-
    (   catch(G, Result, true)
    *-> true
    ;   Result = false(G)
    ).
```

Now you can run e.g.,

```
?- until_failure((Step1 = true,
               Step2 = true, 
               fail,
               Step3 = true), Result),
   writeln([Step1, Step2, Step3]).

[true, true, _5742]
Result = false(fail)
```

See http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/ReQWsvCg.swinb.  SWISH doesn't allow for 
handling mutexes, but you can easily wrap this inside `with_mutex/2`.  The details depend notably on how you want to handle non-determinism.